# TIME display issues

Tags: formula, datetime, formula-field, date

I am using Startdatetime_*c custom field as a Date/Time data type, 
when am inserting a record in salesforce as Startdatetime*_c = 26/03/2014 10:00.This record is inserting as per my request, but when am retrieving the particular record using SOQL query in developer console the Startdatetime__c field shown as **26/03/2014 09:00** 1 hour delay...why it happens? Is there any ways to solve this?

Thanks
VenaktsForce

Comment: what is your organization timezone?

Comment: @highfive This is my Organization Timezone (GMT+00:00) Greenwich Mean Time (Europe/London)

Comment: Doh! in that case my answer may not help you. But can't think of any other possibilities. Is this happen for all the records? What about other datetime fields if any?

Answer (score 4):

`DateTime` field values are stored as Coordinate Universal Time(UTC) in salesforce. When displaying them in a client application, they will be converted to the relevant organization time zone. So in the developer console you will see the values in UTC and if you bind them into a VF page, you can see the converted value.
Check [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm)